# Generate HEIF data using UIGraphicsImageRenderer in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uikit, ios11, uigraphicscontext, heif

I just watched [this WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/511/), and while I'm very excited to adopt HEIF they didn't mention `UIGraphicsRenderer` at all. After scanning the header for the `UIGraphics*Renderer` classes, I didn't see anything notable there either. Is there a way to use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to get HEIF data back on devices running iOS 11?

Comment: There is not at this time. I filed a request for this, you may wish to as well at bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, but I wrote a wrapper here that let's you convert `UIImage`s to HEIC: https://github.com/timonus/UIImageHEIC